# How can I run pdflatex.exe on multiple .tex files on Windows 7?

Tags: command-line, pdflatex

I'd like to run, for example, `pdflatex.exe` on *all* .tex-files whose name start with, say, "Chap03_". How can I do that?

Notes:

- All the .tex-files are always in the same specific folder so I think this could be utilized.
- Because of the same folder, using the beginning of the name is important!
- In some cases I'd also like to use `lualatex.exe` on said files.
- It is very important that only one gets processes at a time, then the next one. Maybe this is an odd bit but I just do not have any experience with this whatsoever.
- The files are all UTF-8 encoded.

I think this leads a batch script? I mean this would be great, just to double-click something and then let magic happen. :)

Comment: did you try using `pdflatex.exe Chap03*` from a cmd-line ? That should usually work.

Comment: @shellter Tried it. Does not work. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by very few lines of codes through many programming languages. The go-ahead is to list all files in your directory, reduce this list by all files starting with "Chap03_" and ending with ".tex". Then call pdflatex on each of these files. This is for instance done in following Python 2.7 script:

```
import os

method = raw_input('Which method do you desire pdflatex/lualatex/xelatex?')
files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())

def fun(i):
    """If i begins with Chap03_ and ends with .tex i is returned else 
    None is retruned"""
    loc1 = i.find('Chap03_')
    loc2 = i.find('.tex')
    if loc1 == 0 and (len(i)-len('.tex')) == loc2:
        return(i)

texFiles = [fun(i) for i in files if fun(i) is not None]
for i in texFiles:
    os.system(method + ' ' +i)
```

The script will search in the folder of which it is placed, or where its parrent program is calling from. In other words just place it in the relevant folder and click on it when you need to compile all the pdfs. The command prompt will ask you which method to use (pdflatex/lualatex/xelatex). If you are not using Python i recomend installing Anaconda2 (Python 2.7), after the installation you will be able to run this script.